# Conflict between okHttp3 and Retrofit. I want to user the .headers() function of Retrofit but it gives me the .headers() of okHttp3. Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, conflict

I'm pretty new on Kotlin language and I was using okHttp3 to connect with my other APIs and It was working fine, but I saw some comments and I start using retrofit instead of okHttp. The problem is, I need the response header to save in my Global class, but when I put response.header() it says that the type required is retrofit2.http.Headers and found okhttp3.Headers even I didn't import the okhttp modules on my class.
There is any way to specify that I want to use the Retrofit headers?

Thats my globalClass

```
package com.example.appfacul
import android.app.Application
import retrofit2.http.Headers

class GlobalClass:Application() {
  var globalUserName = "test"
  var email = ""
  var id = ""
  var responseHeaders = Headers()}
```

Thats my other class that I want to get the Headers

```
override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<AutenticationResponse>,
                response: Response<AutenticationResponse>
            ) {
                    val globalClass = GlobalClass()
                    val resultHeader=response.headers()
                    globalClass.responseHeaders=resultHeader
```

Other Class imports

[image]

And that's the error that the ide shows

[image: IDE error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `retrofit2.http.Headers` type for `var responseHeaders = Headers()` because it's annotation and it's used for another purpose, see the [doc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Headers.html)

Since the headers are key-values pairs then you can just use it like this `var responseHeaders = Map<String, List<String>>`

And just convert `okhttp3.Headers` to map:

```
val resultHeader = response.headers()
globalClass.responseHeaders = resultHeader.toMultimap()
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem following your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Replace `import retrofit2.http.Headers` with `import okhttp3.Headers` and `var responseHeaders = Headers()` with `var responseHeaders = Headers.Builder().build()`